# how to cut a cube to the same size using cell fracture add-on?

Tags: modeling, add-on, cell-fracture

I want to cut a cube to the same size like a cake using cell fracture add-on.

[image]

This is the shape i want to cut. Sorry for the bad quality.

[image]

Which settings in cell fracture add-on should I change?
I need your help ;)

Comment: AFAIK this cannot be done with that add-on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by Chris in comment - addon can't do that, but you can get this result by ...

- Use *Plane*
- *Subdivide*
- *Triangulate*
- add *Edges Split* modifier with angle zero
- add *Solidify* modifier 2m
- Apply modifiers
- *Separate by Loose Parts*
- *Set Origin to Geometry*